# How to connect Linux Virtual Machine from its host computer?

Tags: python, sockets, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm creating a simple chat app using Python.

The server code is in the Linux VM (I am using Virtual Box), and the client code is in the Windows 10 computer where the Virtual Box is installed.

I'm trying to connect it with the Python socket.

It works when I ping both machines to each other.

My problem is what port should I put in the client code:

Client

```
import socket
import subprocess

cliente = socket.socket()

try:
    cliente.connect(('192.168.1.33',9090))
    cliente.send("1")
```

I tried every port available; however, nothing works. I think I am missing something to make this work.

Comment: Do you get some error messages? Timeout or connection refused? First usually is because of firewall and second because your server isn't running on that port. And finally, does it work if you run both server and client on the Linux box?

Comment: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. 
This is the error when I'm trying to run the program.

Comment: Ok, that is connection refused. So your server is not running on that port. Try running the client on Linux box.

Comment: Yes, it works when I run it with the same machine using localhost:9090.

Comment: Does it work when you run with that address (192.168.1.33)? You are sure that your Linux VM has that address.

Comment: Actually, there is an article on ServerFault which may help you. https://serverfault.com/questions/225155/virtualbox-how-to-set-up-networking-so-both-host-and-guest-can-access-internet . This problem is virtual machine related, not in your code.

Comment: When running both server and client to the same machine using 192.168.1.33:9090. It did not work. Do you know which IP I should use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You need to make sure that the port number passed to `bind` function in server code in Linux VM is the same port number used by `connect` function in your client.

Check this simple server-client example in python which is using port 12345             :
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm

Second, (based on your comments) the IP address that should be used in client `connect` function is the IP address of the machine running the server code which is in your case the Linux VM. Try to run the shell command `ifconfig` in the Linux VM to get the IP address.

If this address didn't work you can change the network settings of the virtual machine to **bridged** instead of NAT and try again the `ifconfig` command and get the new IP address.

Comment: According to comments "it works when I run it with the same machine using localhost:9090" So port number is not the issue.

Comment: Yes I just noticed the comments after posting the answer. So, I edited the answer. Actually I can't reply in comments because I am still new here, but I can reply on the comments of my answer

Answer (score 0):

Doing SSH from the host machine to Linux Virtual machine will work great!!